# JSON_AGG as Object not Array - PostgresSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

I have the table "mytable" with many "bad" and "good" records:

```
|id|good|hour |
|1 |t   |12:00|
|2 |f   |12:00|
|3 |t   |13:00|
|4 |t   |13:00|
|5 |t   |13:00|
|6 |f   |14:00|
....
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT 
    h, 
    JSON_AGG(data) 
FROM (
    hour AS h, 
    JSON_BUILD_OBJECT(CASE WHEN good = TRUE THEN 'good' ELSE 'bad' END, COUNT(*)) AS data 
    FROM mytable 
    GROUP BY h, good
) AS foo 
GROUP BY h 
ORDER BY h;
```

And the result I have:

```
 12:00 | [{"good" : 1}, {"bad" : 1}]
 13:00 | [{"good" : 3}]
 14:00 | [{"bad" : 1}]
 ...
```

But the result I want to get:

```
 12:00 | {"good" : 1, "bad" : 1}
 13:00 | {"good" : 3, "bad" : 0}
 14:00 | {"good" : 0, "bad" : 1}
 ...
```

Is there a way to get it (combine two JSON objects into one)?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`json_build_object()` with just one level of aggregation should be enough:

```
select 
    hour as h,
    json_build_object(
        'good',
        count(*) filter (where good = true),
        'bad',
        count(*) filter (where good = false)
    ) js
from mytable
group by hour
order by hour
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=18f9df0d2224f4ae0efe6858eea654e4)**:

```
h     | js                     
:---- | :----------------------
12:00 | {"good" : 1, "bad" : 1}
13:00 | {"good" : 3, "bad" : 0}
14:00 | {"good" : 0, "bad" : 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `JSON_AGG` with `JSON_BUILD_OBJECT`. That should help!

Comment: I've tried this before:( After replacing I get the message: column "foo.data" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function. After adding GROUP BY foo.data another error: "could not identify an equality operator for type json"

Answer (score 1):

if you use `json_build_object`, you will have to enter each field manually, so you may use `to_json`, and the json object (without array) will be automatically generated, hope it will be useful for someone